# Minimize bytes to save chess state with all figures

Tags: java, math, compression, chess, lossless-compression

I want to minimize the bytes need when i save a chess state with all figures:
Currently i need about 18 bytes to store the full board. I simply encode the possible positions for White King and other figures in some number.

```
BigInteger big1 = ZERO;
BigInteger small1 = ONE;


big1 = big1.add(small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(64,1, cache).subtract(ONE))); // White K
small1 = small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(64,1, cache));
big1 = big1.add(small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(63,1, cache).subtract(ONE))); // White Q
small1 = small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(63,1, cache));
big1 = big1.add(small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(62,1, cache).subtract(ONE))); // Black K
small1 = small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(62,1, cache));
big1 = big1.add(small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(61,1, cache).subtract(ONE))); // Black Q
small1 = small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(61,1, cache));
big1 = big1.add(small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(60,2, cache).subtract(ONE))); // White T
small1 = small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(60,2, cache));
big1 = big1.add(small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(58,2, cache).subtract(ONE))); // Black T
small1 = small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(58,2, cache));
big1 = big1.add(small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(56,2, cache).subtract(ONE))); // White H
small1 = small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(56,2, cache));
big1 = big1.add(small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(54,2, cache).subtract(ONE))); // Black H
small1 = small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(54,2, cache));
big1 = big1.add(small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(52,2, cache).subtract(ONE))); // White R
small1 = small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(52,2, cache));
big1 = big1.add(small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(50,2, cache).subtract(ONE))); // Black R 
small1 = small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(50,2, cache));
big1 = big1.add(small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(48,8, cache).subtract(ONE))); // White P
small1 = small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(48,8, cache));
big1 = big1.add(small1.multiply(tn.binomialCache(40,8, cache).subtract(ONE))); // Black P

// nummber of states which a full chessboard can have
// big1 = 4634726695587809641192045982323285670400000
```

Its possible do encode/decode the state of a chess board with all figures to less to than 18bytes?

Comment: It may be possible using some kind of variant of [FEN-Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation), i.e. instead of using  full bytes to represent a `P` (for pawn) you could assign it some number (possibly less than a byte). Encoding the whole chessboard as just a very long binary sequence

Comment: "All figures"? Do you mean all 32 pieces are on the board? How is that useful? You soon need to deal with captures. Also you need to handle promotions.

Comment: You may be interested in checking out how this is done in [Lila chess engine](https://github.com/LeelaChessZero/lc0/blob/master/src/chess/bitboard.h) and [stockfish](https://codecatalog.org/articles/stockfish-board-representation/). These are real chess engines that account for _valid_ positions/moves/captures, special rules like en passant, castles.

Answer (score 1):

For all all 32 pieces still on the board, there is a bound of 1.89x10<sup>33</sup> states. That could be encoded in 14 bytes. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.09386.pdf . Not sure how that's useful though, since there is such a thing as captures. You'd also need to handle other possible sets of pieces, due to promotions.